# Difference between timekey and flush_interval

Tags: fluentd

I configured a fluentd forwarder service to collect logs of multiple fluentd instance and forward collected to an Elasticsearch cluster.

I configured the forwarder to buffer logs in chunks:

```
<match **>
  @type elasticsearch
  ...
  <buffer time>
    @type file
    ...
    flush_interval 30s
    timekey 30
    ...
  </buffer>
```

On this part I got confused about the usage of `timekey` and `flush_interval`. The [documentation](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/buffer-section) sounds very similar between the two. For `timekey`:

> Output plugin will flush chunks per specified time (enabled when time is specified in chunk keys)

and for `flush_interval`:

> flushes/writes chunks per specified time via flush_interval

Do I only need one of those specified or both?

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/buffer-section

> If the argument time and the parameter timekey (required) are
> specified, the output plugin writes events into chunks grouped by time
> key.

And for flushing:

> Following are the flushing parameters for chunks to optimize
> performance (latency and throughput)

So in my understanding:

The **timekey** serves for grouping data in chunks by time, but not for saving/sending chunks.

The **flush_interval** defines how often the prepared chunk will be saved to disk/memory.